# Can you animate/Tween camera.followBodyComponent

Tags: flame

I am trying to animate, from not follow a Component, to follow a Component - and then lastly animate back again to not following the component.

```
// this.camera.follow = Tween()
this.camera.followBodyComponent(SomeComponent);
```

Do you know how?

I tried something like this:

```
  bool tappedComponent = false;
  Vector2 cameraGoToPosition = Vector2(0,0);
  Vector2 cameraFromPosition = Vector2(0,0);

  void zoomTo(BodyComponent body, Vector2 vec){
    cameraFromPosition = body.center;
    camera.follow = cameraGoToPosition;
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    cameraGoToPosition = cameraGoToPosition * dt;
    camera.position = cameraGoToPosition;
  }
```

But `camera.position` has no setter or getter?

Update: found that:

```
camera.moveTo(body.center);
// camera.moveTo(worldToScreen(body.center));
```

Is moving in an animated way, but it do not put the Component in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way currently is probably to just do:

```dart
camera.moveTo(body.center + camera.canvasSize / 2);
```

This will be improved for the `CameraComponent` API.